# Split multiple EDI segments into separate files

Tags: java, string, split, java-11, edi

I have an input as below, which contains two EDI segments in a single file which starts with ST* and ends with SE*.. now I have to split this into two file, but both output should have the first 2 and bottom 2 lines as it is..

Note: the number of segments can vary..

**input:**

```
    GS*SH*4405197800*999999999*20111206*1045*49*X*004060~
    ST*997*0008*3~
    AK1*AA*49*001000~
    AK2*997*001*REFNO~
    SE*8*0008~
    ST*997*0009*3~
    AK1*SH*8150406~
    AK2*856*8150406~
    AK3*N3*2*N1*3~
    SE*8*0008~
    GE*1*49~
    IEA*1*000000049~
```

How can I separate this as two independent files like below more performance efficiently in java,

**output 1:**

```
ISA*01*0000000000*01*0000000000*ZZ*ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO*ZZ*123456789012345*101127*1719*U*00400*000003438*0*P*>~
GS*SH*4405197800*999999999*20111206*1045*49*X*004060~
ST*997*0008*3~
AK1*AA*49*001000~
AK2*997*001*REFNO~
SE*8*0008~
GE*1*49~
IEA*1*000000049~
```

**output 2:**

```
ISA*01*0000000000*01*0000000000*ZZ*ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO*ZZ*123456789012345*101127*1719*U*00400*000003438*0*P*>~
GS*SH*4405197800*999999999*20111206*1045*49*X*004060~
ST*997*0009*3~
AK1*SH*8150406~
AK2*856*8150406~
AK3*N3*2*N1*3~
SE*8*0008~
GE*1*49~
IEA*1*000000049~
```

Comment: Do you have a working program and want to improve it's performance? If so, please provide the necessary code.
If not, do you have a *not* working program or maybe a starting idea on how to tackle this? Please also share. ;)

Comment: @Eskapone, I don`t have a working program but a starting an idea of splitting the file as array using ~ as delimiter and traverse through it.

Comment: I would suggest writing both files as you read the input file, so working with 3 streams.
Read from Input, first two lines -> into both output streams, first "ST" block -> into first output stream until "SE", second "ST" block -> into second output stream until "SE", last two lines -> into both output streams. close all streams. That way your program does not need to store much data at any time.

+ the file seems to be line based, so you do not need '~' as a delimiter. Just take a line based file reader, e.g. BufferedReader.

Comment: got it.. the segments count may vary as some file might have 5+ segments in it.. any approach on how to dynamically handle that ?

Comment: yes, save the first two lines and create files and output streams dynamically with each segment you find, write the first two lines, then the segment you found and leave a reference (e.g. some list of output streams) to write the last two lines later.